# creating multiple variables in loops in r

Tags: r, loops

I am quite new to R, and I do not know how to create variables in a loop. I have a dataset where each observation is uniquely defined by an id and a type. My goal would be to create different datasets from a starting one, keeping for each dataset the id, type a specific variable, and to rename the variable type as type_variable. Please see below a reproducible example of my dataset:

```
dt_type <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                      type= c("b1", "b2","c1", "c2","b1", "b2","c1", "c2"),
                      a=rnorm(8), b=rnorm(8),c=rnorm(8),d=rnorm(8))
# id type           a          b          c           d
# 1  1   b1 -0.74733339 -1.1121249 -0.2005649  1.70320036
# 2  1   b2 -0.87290362 -0.1221949 -2.7723691  1.04158671
# 3  1   c1 -0.00878965 -0.7592988 -0.5108226  2.10755315
# 4  1   c2  0.87295622 -0.5885439  0.2606365 -0.87080649
# 5  2   b1 -0.74536372  0.1377794 -0.1382621  0.01743011
# 6  2   b2 -0.01570109 -0.3058672 -0.3146880 -0.43594081
# 7  2   c1 -0.28966205 -0.2045772 -1.1776759 -2.24223369
# 8  2   c2 -0.63680969  2.3815740  0.4462243 -0.05397941
```

This is how I have tried to do it, but unfortunately it does not work.

```
varlist <- list("a", "b", "c", "d")
for (i in 1:4) {
  tmp <- dt_type %>% rename(paste("type", varlist[[i]], sep=="_") = type)  %>%
    arrange(id, varlist[[i]], desc(paste("type", varlist[[i]], sep=="_"))) %>%
    distinct(id, varlist[[i]], .keep_all = T)
  assign(paste("dt_type_", varlist[[i]]), tmp)
}
```

I am used to using loops in other programming languages, but if there are better ways to reach the result I want, please let me know.

Sorry for not posting the expected output, here it is:

```
dt_type_a
#    id type      value
# 1  1   b1 -1.5023199
# 2  1   b2 -0.3653626
# 3  1   c1  1.2842098
# 4  1   c2  0.2732327
# 5  2   b1 -0.7581897
# 6  2   b2  1.1627059
# 7  2   c1 -1.6644546
# 8  2   c2  1.2916819

dt_type_b
#    id type       value
# 1  1   b1 -0.19573684
# 2  1   b2 -1.35095843
# 3  1   c1  0.69342205
# 4  1   c2  0.47689611
# 5  2   b1  0.67058845
# 6  2   b2  0.21992074
# 7  2   c1 -0.02046201
# 8  2   c2  0.19686712
```

Thanks,
Vincenzo

Comment: Can you also show what is your exact *expected output* is given your input in a reproducible format?

Comment: Looks to me that you want to `pivot_longer()` and then `split()` by type_*

Comment: And if you are having trouble showing what your expected output is, perhaps you could simplify your input even more---maybe "a" and "b" are enough to illustrate the problem and "c" and "d" can be dropped.

Comment: Thank you all! Indeed I was able to get what I wanted with the pivot_longer command, thanks! However, could you also help me understand how to do it in loops? In some other parts of my code, I want to create variables within loops but I am not able to do so

Comment: in a for loop: `result = list(); for(i in 3:6) result[[paste0('dt_type_', names(dt_type)[i])]] = dt_type[, c(1:2, i)]; result` then you could do `attach(result)` and now try calling `dt_type_a`. But I would highly advice to keep it in the list rather than having it in the environment/searchpath

Comment: Thank you! and how would you rename the variable type within the loop? using paste() within the rename yields an error

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I would just go from wide to long but since you're asking to create variables dynamically:

```
library(data.table)

dt_type <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2), 
                      type= c("b1", "b2","c1", "c2","b1", "b2","c1", "c2"),
                      a=rnorm(8), b=rnorm(8),c=rnorm(8),d=rnorm(8))

setDT(dt_type)

dt_long <- melt(dt_type, id.vars = c("id", "type"))

varnames <- unique(dt_long$variable)

for (var in varnames) {
  assign(paste0("dt_type_", var), dt_long[variable == var, .(id, type, value)])
}
```

hope it helps...